# How to put a image inside table from my database?

Tags: php

This is a code from my table

I want to put image of each car from my database, how can i do that???

After id should be a image....

## ,image,Mærke,Model,Pris,Årgang,

```
<table>

            <tr>

                <th>#</th>
                <th>Mærke</th>
                <th>Model</th>
                <th>Pris</th>
                <th>Årgang</th>

            </tr>

    <?php

    $allCarsResult = $dbCon -> query("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE category_fk = 1");

    while($allCars = $allCarsResult->fetch_object()){

    ?>

            <tr>
                <td><?=$allCars->id ?></td>
                <td><?=$allCars->brand ?></td>
                <td><?=$allCars->model ?></td>
                <td><?=$allCars->price ?></td>
                <td><?=$allCars->year ?></td>
                <td><a href="?page=104&id=<?=$allCars->id ?>">Rediger</a></td>
                <td><a href="?page=103&delete&id=<?=$allCars->id ?>">X</a></td>
            </tr>

    <?php

    }

    ?>

        </table>
```

Comment: OMG man, what the heck is this? Please format your code.

Comment: How can i format it?

Comment: You can always start by reading other questions, FAQ and such things. You can also use the editor that comes with this site. Also, "after id should be a image" - image **path**, image **binary contents**, what? Dumping code like this and expecting we can read your mind won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store your image path in the `image` field in your database, you can use this.

```
$allCarsResult = query("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE category_fk = 1");
while ($allCars = $allCarsResult->fetch_object()) {
    ?> 
    <img src="<?php echo $allCars->image; ?>" alt=" " />
    <?php
}
```

Comment: I tried that, if i do like that it shows only the name of the images, but i want display the images

Comment: the path is good, i need to put inside the table how can i do that? the exemple you gave me is not usefull